# Bot Framework C# not generating/storing OAuth2 tokens in the Token Service

Tags: c#, botframework, keycloak, single-sign-on, bot-emulator

I'm using the bot framework sample from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph and using a Generic OAuth2 Provider (Keycloak).

I can log in successfully and get a new token when using the feature 'Test Connection' through Azure Portal.

When using the emulator I can log in successfully but the GetToken endpoint from the Token Service returns 404 (Not Found).

I'm trying to find a way to debug or check some logs from the Token Service, but it seems they don't provide anything related to that. I tested using ADv2 and it worked as expected.

Screenshot of what happens after asking to show the token:
[image]

1. Is there a way to check why the Token Service fails to get a token?
2. Should I configure the Exchange Endpoint?

Comment: If you have a 404 response maybe it's because the url you request is wrong

Comment: @ClemB When the GetToken request is triggered I can see it reaching the Keycloak instance and the Token being refreshed successfully in the logs. Despite that, it still returns 404.